# Number of locks JVM can hold at once without sacrificing performance

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Suppose you have a work queue and there can be thousands of work items. And assume updates for different work items keep coming into the system. Now obviously if we get multiple updates for the same work item, that needs to be locked.

In this situation we can easily run into a situation, where the system could have received 2000 (or some high number) updates at once and hence JVM needs to hold 2000 locks on different objects.

Will it degrade JVM performance alot? Is there any maximum number of locks that JVM can hold at once to not let performance degrade.

I understand you can use hashing technique to stop the number of locks from growing.

Comment: Why don't you write a small test class to try it out?

Comment: "Will it degrade JVM performance alot ?" - Could you define "a lot" somehow? It would help to understand your situation a bit better.

Comment: My feeling is that *contended* locks are far more significant then locks per-se.

Comment: I can write a simple program on one machine, but I am trying to see if there are any general guidelines to things like this.

Comment: @AndreyTaptunov may be, does the performance degrade linearly (inverse)? Say performance with 10k lock at once will be 1/5 of the performance with 2k locks?

Answer (score 1):

Any locking in a multicore scenario involves atomic memory operations, i.e., one core seeing data written by another core (after it has been written). This data must be pushed out to memory by one core (telling all the other core’s caches that whatever they know about this value is invalid and must be refreshed) and read in at the other core. How fast this can happen varies a lot between CPU architectures and their implementation. Single-socket machines in general, should be faster at this than multi-sockets.

---

Therefore, as SimonC said, you need to write a test.

Answer (score 1):

Each lock merely stores the object holding it. The first part of the question--how many locks can the JVM hold--is like asking how many `12`s it can store. The amount is bounded by memory. As others have noted, performance is impacted most by lock *contention*.

Use the classes from `java.util.concurrent` to build and store your locks and work queue as they were written for safety and performance. I highly recommend the book [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601).